# How do I get the ID of the active theme from the Theme API

Tags: shopify

Using the Shopify Theme API ([Link](http://api.shopify.com/theme.html#show)), I'd like to be able to get the theme ID for the currently active (main) theme.

I'm using the api gem as follows:

```
Shopify::Theme.find(:all, :params => { :role => 'published' })
```

It returns every installed theme and not just the main, published theme.  Can I access a Theme this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't filter on role the way you're trying to.

However, seeing as each shop can only have a maximum of 8 themes it's not much effort to simply grab all the themes with `ShopifyAPI::Theme.all` and then search through them for the one being used as the main one.

Comment: Thanks David.  That's easy enough to do.  Is there a way to know by looking at the API docs what fields can and can't be used in this way?

Comment: There's a small section above the first example on each page of the API docs titled 'Available URL Query Parameters' that tells you what you can add via params.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try getting the ID through Assets like this:

```
@theme_asset = ShopifyAPI::Asset.find('layout/theme.liquid')
@theme_asset.theme_id
```